# No puedo encontrar el error en el codigo Python

Tags: python, backend, python-3.10

**TARREA:**

Crea una función que reciba dos cadenas como parámetro (str1, str2)
e imprima otras dos cadenas como salida (out1, out2).

- out1 contendrá todos los caracteres presentes en la str1 pero NO
  estén presentes en str2.
- out2 contendrá todos los caracteres presentes en la str2 pero NO
  estén presentes en str1.

**CÓDIGO:**

```
def my_function():
    str_1 = " cafe"
    str_2 = " Leche"

    str1 = str_1.upper()
    str2 = str_2.upper()


    my_str1_list = list(str1)
    my_str2_list = list(str2)
    my_str3_list = list()

    my_str3_list = my_str1_list.copy()

    for item1, item2 in zip(my_str1_list, my_str2_list):
         if item1 in my_str2_list:
             my_str1_list.remove(item1)

    for item2, item3 in zip(my_str2_list, my_str3_list):
        if item2 in my_str3_list:
            my_str2_list.remove(item2)
         

    out1 = list()
    out2 = list()

    out1 = my_str1_list.copy()
    out2 = my_str2_list.copy()


    print(" ")
    print("· Caracteres presentes en la primera palabra, pero NO\npresentes en la segunda, son los siguientes: {}".format(out1))
    print(" ")
    print("· Caracteres presentes en la segunda palabra, pero NO\npresentes en la primera, son los siguientes: {}".format(out2))
    print(" ")

  my_function()
```

**RESULTADO EN LA TERMINAL:**

· Caracteres presentes en la primera palabra, pero NO
presentes en la segunda, son los siguientes: ['C', 'A', 'F']

· Caracteres presentes en la segunda palabra, pero NO
presentes en la primera, son los siguientes: ['L', 'C', 'H']

P.S. Como podéis ver, la letra "C" se repite. No pasa solo con estas palabras. Si a las palabras indicadas en **str_1** y **str_2** les añadimos muchas letras repetitivas, en la salida aparecerán. Espero vuestra respuesta. Soy nuevo en Python.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu ciclo al iterar nunca obtiene esa "c", por lo que no se elimina.

### Invalidación de iteradores

Nunca debes modificar el tamaño de un iterador mientras iteras sobre el con un ciclo `for in`. Es decir, nunca debes agregar o eliminar items del mismo.

En tu caso, el primer carácter es el espacio, que al cumplir la condición de existir en la segunda cadena es eliminado. En la segunda iteración el `for` obtiene el segundo item de la lista, pero este ahora ya no es la "C", sino la "a", por lo que que la "c" se salta.

Exactamente lo mismo ocurre con la "c" en el segundo ciclo, se elimina la letra que le precede, la "e", y el ciclo se vuelve a saltar la "c".

Puedes ver el problema con el siguiente código:

```
palabra = list("leche")

for letra in palabra:
    print(letra)
    if letra == "e":
        palabra.remove("e")
```

> ```
> l
> e
> h
> e
> ```

Por lo tanto, como norma general evita eliminar items del mismo iterable a la vez que iteras sobre el. Hay excepciones siempre y cuando sepas lo que haces y tengas garantizado/documentado como se implementa el iterador internamente, pero en general, simplemente no lo hagas.

Hay alternativas, como eliminar sobre una copia del mismo:

```
palabra = list("leche")

for letra in palabra.copy():
    if letra == "e":
        palabra.remove("e")

print(palabra)
```

o usar otra aproximación, como recorrer el iterable en orden inverso usando indexado, en cuyo caso si es seguro eliminar items ya que no se invalidan los indices de los elementos por recorrer:

```
palabra = list("leche")

for i in range(len(palabra) - 1, -1, -1):
    if palabra[i] == "e":
        del palabra[i]

print(palabra)
```

---

En tu problema concreto, realmente no necesitas para nada las listas auxiliares ni eliminar nada, simplemente recorre cada cadena y ve generando la de salida con los caracteres que no están presentes en la otra.

El uso de `zip` tampoco es necesario en este caso, de hecho ni siquiera haces uso del segundo componente generado por `zip` en cada ciclo.

Puedes por tanto hacer simplemente algo como:

```
def my_function(str_1, str_2):
    str_1 = str_1.upper()
    str_2 = str_2.upper()

    out_1 = []
    out_2 = []

    for char in str_1:
        if char not in str_2 and char not in out_1:
            out_1.append(char)

    for char in str_2:
        if char not in str_1 and char not in out_2:
            out_2.append(char)

    print(
        "\n· Caracteres presentes en la primera palabra, pero NO\n"
        f"presentes en la segunda, son los siguientes: {out_1}\n"
        )

    print(
        "\n· Caracteres presentes en la segunda palabra, pero NO\n"
        f"presentes en la primera, son los siguientes: {out_2}\n"
        )


my_function(" cafe", " leche")
```

---

Si no importa el orden de las letras en la salida, una forma muy eficiente de hacer esto es usar diferencia de conjuntos:

```
def my_function(str_1, str_2):
    str_1_set = set(str_1.upper())
    str_2_set = set(str_2.upper())

    out_1 = str_1_set - str_2_set
    out_2 = str_2_set - str_1_set
    print(
        "\n· Caracteres presentes en la primera palabra, pero NO\n"
        f"presentes en la segunda, son los siguientes: {out_1}\n"
        )

    print(
        "\n· Caracteres presentes en la segunda palabra, pero NO\n"
        f"presentes en la primera, son los siguientes: {out_2}\n"
        )


my_function(" cafe", " leche")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, FJSevilla. Muchísimas gracias.